# Object function router(req, res, next) { router.handle(req, res, next); } has no method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just want to insert a row in mysql database. I have installed passport and also hjs.I am just sending the value of a form from app.js to a js file and there I want to insert the data. But there showing the error message:

```
Object function router(req, res, next) { router.handle(req, res, next); } 
has no method 'addUser'
```

## My `app.js` code

SQL driver

```
var db = require('./db');
```

Configuring Passport

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

The route where I want to perform the action

```
var add = require('./routes/dosignup');

app.post('/dosignup', function(req, res, next) { 
  add.addUser(req.body);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

On `dosignup` page which is situated in routes folder.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('./db');

var addUser = {};

exports.addUser = function(usr){
    console.log(usr);
    var details = {
        title: usr.title,
        firstname: usr.firstname
    };

    db.query('INSERT into  `users` SET ?', details, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log(' The value inserted. ');
    });
};

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the last line:

```
module.exports = router;
```

You are assigning your `addUser` function to the exports object, but then you override it with this line and return `router` instead.

From the looks of it, you don't need router or any express related stuff in `dosignup`, so you can just remove it. But if you do need it for some parts that does not appear here, just return it in the same way you do with `addUser`:

```
exports.router = router;
```

That way the returned object will contain both `router` and `addUser`